# Woocommerce Wcvendors - duplicate emails when Vendor approved

Tags: user-roles, email

I am building a marketplace using WC Vendors on top of Woocommerce.  The vendors apply by completing a form, which creates a user with the role 'pending vendor'.  As admin, I then click 'approve' or 'deny' by their username in the Users table in the backend.

However, when I click 'approve' on a user, the two emails that get sent (one to admin, one to the user) are each sent three times.

I've tried deactivating the template override for that notification, and the plugin I'd used to style up the emails.  But nothing seems to stick.

What is the next step in diagnosing this?  Has anyone come across this before?

Cheers, in frustration!

Comment: You should confirm that the emails are getting duplicated by WordPress and not by your email system. I'd then probably find the code that's sending the email and try and trace back what it's hooked to, to see if you've registered that a few times. Or you can add trace to the code that's sending these emails to log out the call stack that it has been called from, the name of the action that triggered it, etc. and see if that helps.

Comment: I'd also ask the WC Vendors authors for help too if you haven't already.

Comment: Thanks Rup.  I've emailed wcvendors already, waiting on that.  I have a mail log plugin in the back end which confirms that there are 3x emails for those two notifications.  I've gone through the plugin source to look for the approval functions and searched elsewhere, to no avail.  :-(

Answer (score 1):

Our emails for deny/approval are triggered when the user role changes. If you have any plugins or theme overrides that are calling these actions at the wrong time, this can cause multiple emails to be fired.

As per our support discussion we were able to narrow it down to code within your child theme. Are you able to update your question with the particular piece of code that was causing this issue?

Comment: Hi Jamie - I removed an unrelated chunk of code that wasn't enqueuing a script correctly from the child theme's functions.php, and the error stopped.  Thanks for your help in trying to track it down with us!

Comment: Great! Would you be able to update the issue with the kind of code that was breaking things? I'd also like to add it to our new docs site I'm working on.